# How to do regression using svmtrain() function in libsvm (what settings)? what is the label matrix form?

Tags: matlab, octave

Libsvm is a small library for support vector machines written in C. here is the link to the source of libsvm I've used ( https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm ). Can someone correct the options in the svmtrain() function or label matrix in the following code to perform regression successfully, since the output says optimization finished with #0 iteration.

The goal of the code before svmtrain() function is to arrange water pixels of an underwater color image (some rect in image) into an (m x 3) matrix as data. The label matrix is an ( m x 1 ) vector preset to 1;{   [here is the link to the underwater image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JrCu.png), [equation of red channel compensation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwxpH.png)   }

the output:

```
optimization finished, #iter = 0
nu = 0.000000
obj = 0.000000, rho = -1.000000
nSV = 0, nBSV = 0
```

here is the code:

```
    ##to load image package
    pkg load image
    ## add the path to the matlab folder inside the LIBSVM package source
    addpath('./libsvm-master/libsvm-master/matlab')
    ##load libsvm 
    pkg load statistics
    ##load an under water rgb image
    im = imread('9554.png');
    im=double(im);
    startrow=1;
    startcol=1;
    endrow=100;
    endcol=100;
    ## save rgb pixels in m x 3 form
    data=zeros(endrow*endcol,3,'double');
    for i=startrow:endrow
      for j=startcol:endcol
        data((i-1)*endrow+j,1:3)=im(i,j,1:3);
      end
    end
    ## m x 1 label matrix, all preset to 1
    label_data=ones(size(data,1),1,'double');
    model=svmtrain(label_data,data,'-s 3 -c 1');
```

Comment: are you sure you're calling the libsvm `svmtrain` as opposed to the statistics pkg `svmtrain` function? (which simply warns you this function is not yet implemented)

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou  To successfully run the svmtrain() function defined in libsvm from  https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm, you should make the library according to the readme file. The make is very easy. It only needs to run the make.m in matlab folder inside the package source from github.
I still can't find the options for regression but I managed to use two labels instead of one label. This way worked succefully. Here are the input arguments and options:
Model = svmtrain ( label_data , data , '-c 1 -g 0.07' );

Comment: So the answer to my question is that you ran it from within the package directory? Would you like to share your input image so that I can run your code on my machine?

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou   yes, to successfully running the code in Octave/Matlab and to avoid getting 'undefined function' error, it is need to add the path to the matlab folder inside the LIBSVM package source. e.g. addpath('/ the path to the matlab folder')

Comment: btw, is this related to the ImageClef challenge by any chance? :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing the image and extra details.

I think the problem is simply that you're passing a 'labels' matrix which consists only of a single label. The algorithm detects that there is no data to train with, and stops.

If you make some of the labels into zeros, then the algorithm runs as expected.